# select data from 3 tables in laravel by using Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I am new to laravel and stuck on getting data using Eloquent ORM.

My Scenario is I have 3 tables

1. user -  Contains user info
2. location - Contains Location info
3. location_user - Contains user id , location id , time when the user visited that location.

Now a user can visit a location multiple times and a location can be visited by multiple users.

I want to get all location name that a user visited on particular date.

But unable to get.

Below is the db structure

location_user table - id    user_id     location_id     visitedtime

location table      - id    latitude    longitude   locality

user table          - id    name    phone   email

and In user model I have defined the relation

```
public function locations()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('Location')->withPivot('visitedtime');
}
```

when i use this function in controller then i get all the locations visited by that user

```
User::find(2)->locations()->select('locations.locality',locations.id')->get()
```

How can put condition on visitedtime on the above function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User::find(2)
     ->locations()
     ->select('locations.locality',locations.id')
     ->where('pivot_visitedtime', $someDate)
     // or
     // ->where('location_user.visitedtime', $someDate)
     ->get()

// and for $someDate you can use Carbon bc it's stupid-simple, eg.:
$someDate = Carbon::parse('yesterday');
```

Comment: Hi Jarek, thnx for solution. can i exclude the pivot data from the result.